# Различные показания температуры в зависимости от кода

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

*Я "новенький" среди ардуинщиков.*

Есть датчик температуры, есть кнопки. Когда я в `loop()` измеряю только температуру - всё отлично, но как только я добавляю кусок кода - температура моментально меняеться...

**Использовать `delay()` нельзя!**

Код, когда всё хорошо:

```
float TEMPERATURE;
float PRESET_TEMPERATURE = 30.0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  TEMPERATURE = analogRead(A1);
  TEMPERATURE = TEMPERATURE * 0.48828125;
  Serial.println("Temperature: " + String(TEMPERATURE)); 
}
```

Показания:

```
19:10:02.172 -> Temperature: 24.90
19:10:02.206 -> Temperature: 25.39
19:10:02.206 -> Temperature: 24.90
19:10:02.244 -> Temperature: 24.90
19:10:02.244 -> Temperature: 24.90
19:10:02.275 -> Temperature: 24.90
19:10:02.308 -> Temperature: 24.90
19:10:02.308 -> Temperature: 24.90
19:10:02.343 -> Temperature: 24.90
19:10:02.377 -> Temperature: 24.90
19:10:02.377 -> Temperature: 24.90
19:10:02.411 -> Temperature: 25.39
19:10:02.411 -> Temperature: 24.90
19:10:02.445 -> Temperature: 25.39
```

Когда не хорошо:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);

#define BTN_UP   1
#define BTN_DOWN 2
#define BTN_LEFT 3
#define BTN_RIGHT 4
#define BTN_SELECT 5
#define BTN_NONE 10

float TEMPERATURE;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}
void loop() {
  TEMPERATURE = analogRead(A1);
  TEMPERATURE = TEMPERATURE * 0.48828125;
  Serial.println("Temperature: " + String(TEMPERATURE));

  int button = detectButton();
  switch (button) {
    case BTN_UP:
      delay(500);
      break;
    case BTN_DOWN:
      delay(500);
      break;
    case BTN_LEFT:
      delay(500);
      break;
    case BTN_RIGHT:
      delay(500);
      break;
    case BTN_SELECT:
      delay(500);
      break;
 }

}
int detectButton() {
  int keyAnalog =  analogRead(A0);
  if (keyAnalog < 100) {
    return BTN_RIGHT;
  } else if (keyAnalog < 200) {
    return BTN_UP;
  } else if (keyAnalog < 400) {
    return BTN_DOWN;
  } else if (keyAnalog < 600) {
    return BTN_LEFT;
  } else if (keyAnalog < 800) {
    return BTN_SELECT;
  } else {
    return BTN_NONE;
  }
}
```

Показания:

```
19:16:26.434 -> Temperature: 28.81
19:16:26.434 -> Temperature: 28.32
19:16:26.468 -> Temperature: 26.86
19:16:26.468 -> Temperature: 27.83
19:16:26.503 -> Temperature: 28.32
19:16:26.537 -> Temperature: 26.86
19:16:26.537 -> Temperature: 27.83
19:16:26.572 -> Temperature: 27.83
19:16:26.606 -> Temperature: 27.34
19:16:26.606 -> Temperature: 28.32
19:16:26.641 -> Temperature: 28.32
19:16:26.641 -> Temperature: 28.32
19:16:26.676 -> Temperature: 27.34
```

> Скриншоты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Непонятна ваша работа со счетчиком для усреднения. К моменту когда вы попадаете внутрь `if`, сумма `AVERAGE_TEMPERATURE` будет содержать 101 замер температуры. А делите вы на 100. Причем из-за того, что после усреднения вы не обнуляете `AVERAGE_TEMPERATURE`, второе и последующие усреднения в качестве первого слагаемого из этих 101 будут использовать предыдущее усреднение. Это так задумано?

Comment: Усреднение можно не смотреть, я не исправил ещё. Да и причина не в усреднении...

Comment: Попробуйте весь добавляемый код убрать, сократить его до `int keyAnalog =  analogRead(A0);` Будет ли наблюдаться эффект?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `delay(500)` в вашу первую версию кода - что будет? Возможно проблема в том, что в первой версии вы делаете `analogRead` чаще, чем ADC успевает формировать осмысленные значения. Иногда вместо задержки советуют делать `analogRead` дважды, игнорируя первое чтение. Т.е. альтернативно попробуйте `analogRead(A1); TEMPERATURE = analogRead(A1);`. Стабилизируется ли от этого поведение двух вариантов?

Comment: Сейчас пробну использовать analogRead дважды.

Comment: Если дважды делать чтение, то стабилизировалось, но использовать `delay()` мне нельзя, т.к. использую `lcd keypad shield` и кнопку можно нажать во время задержки. Попробую использовать это дальше, но пока не знаю будет ли это верным решением.

Comment: Мне друг подсказал использовать `аппаратный таймер`.

Comment: @RomanShubenko Что означает фраза "использовать аппаратный таймер"? Функция `delay` - это уже использование аппаратного таймера. А если вы вздумали писать прерывание по таймеру - то это полнейшая профанация. Для такой некритичной к таймингу задачи, как опрос датчика температуры, этого не нужно.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Пересмотрев тонны инфы, я нашёл пример скетча "**[Blink without Delay](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay)**", который решил мою проблему... Теперь, когда я начал добавлять больше и больше кода, значения температуры оставались стабильными и более точными.*

*Возможно я ошибаюсь, но это помогло мне.*

```
double TEMPERATURE = 0;

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;       
const long interval = 1500;           

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {

    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    analogRead(A1);
    double TEMPERATURE = analogRead(A1) * 0.48;
    Serial.println("Temperature: " + String(TEMPERATURE));

  }
}
```

Comment: Ну то есть дело было именно в том, что вы слишком часто читали аналоговый вход. К Blink without delay эта тема никак не относится, но способ организации задержки лучше использовать именно такой.

Comment: delay использовать нельзя было, потому что у меня есть ещё и кнопки. `Blink without delay` как раз и относится, потому что там показан способ организации задержки.